# infinite scroll on linkedin with selenium and scrape comments

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape all the comments from all posts from post section of a profile and for that i need to scroll the page to the end so i am trying to find a way through which i can scroll to the end of page and if the page still loads scroll down till the page reaches the end i found many results on this site but they were using time.sleep to wait till the loading completes while scrolling and if the time.sleep ends and the page is still loading then the scrolling will stop as the condition fails so i am trying to find a good way to solve this problem.Also i am not able to get the comments i searched the inspect element but is does not show comments till i click on it and it will be very long process if i click on comment button of every post so i need to find a more effecient way to do that too .
Thank you
Here is my existing code for scrolling down:-

```
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(1)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Comment: you should read selenium documentation: [wait.until()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)